# object gets turned into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My object is getting turned into an array

```
this.projects = {};
var outerThis = this;

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  console.log(this.projects); // at this point projects is Object {}
  if(!(i in Object.keys(this.projects))){
      this.projects[i] = {title:"", trackOneUrl:"", trackTwoUrl:""};
      console.log(this.projects); // now its [object object]
      return;
  }
}
```

when I do:

```
this.projects[i] = {title:"", trackOneUrl:"", trackTwoUrl:""}
```

`projects` goes from being an Object to an Array.

What I was trying to achieve is

```
{'1':{title:"", trackOneUrl:"", trackTwoUrl:""}}
```

instead I get

```
[{title:"", trackOneUrl:"", trackTwoUrl:""}]
```

Comment: Look at your code, you're treating your object like an array so you're going to get array like behavior

Comment: Running this code in node yields `{ '0': { title: '', trackOneUrl: '', trackTwoUrl: '' } }` which looks correct based on your desired outcome.

Comment: Did you try using this.projects.i = /// your assignment. https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/25810/

Comment: @Aj1 That seems like the way to go, I suggest you make that into an answer and explain why the way he's currently trying to do it is mutating his object into an array!

Comment: `[object Object]` is not an array.

Comment: Where do you get an array?  This will *not* convert the object to an array.  https://jsfiddle.net/htnyae0p/

Comment: Sure will do. Thank you @Nick Zuber

Comment: @Nick Zuber you can't use a number for a key in an object unless you use array notation.

Comment: @Gho5t what if you stringify the number?

Comment: @Nick Zuber how without using array notation? What he has actually is the way to do it.

Comment: @Gho5t if he really wants a number as a key to his object, what he's asking for is an array

Comment: @Gho5t numbers to index an object is an array - if the numbers are sparse it's considered a sparse array

Comment: Obviously using numbers as keys in an object doesn't magically make the object have a prototype of an array e.g. have a length property or slice and push methods. Furthermore, if you set your indexes manually in an array e.g. array[3] any gaps are filled with empty elements which is pretty hacky and would give you a misleading length property.

Comment: @peteb Yes in node for some reason it works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this.projects` will remain an object and it does exactly what you wanted it to be.

That `[object Object]` doesn't mean your `projects` becomes an array, that's a string representation of an object. Try calling `String({})` and you will see the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

this.projects is what is known as an object literal. `{}`

Create and array literal using `[]`

From there you can assign an object to each **index** in the array using a simple for loop.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. The user is trying to create an object and use `obj[]` to access the properties on the object.

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work fine if you take out the return.